# Google treats mail from my mail server as spam

Tags: linux, postfix, gmail

Does anyone know what's wrong with my server? Messages are sent to spam.

```
Delivered-To: donia.chromik@gmail.com
Received: by 10.103.46.145 with SMTP id u139csp1708503vsu;
        Sat, 27 Jan 2018 08:11:51 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AH8x224s6S3Ox03gmx45fvpGjiWREAgvgYbemz0CGWwtepJyyNHaZqu+/7y9c4jjM59ilL0fNbPZ
X-Received: by 10.28.1.73 with SMTP id 70mr13258830wmb.49.1517069511460;
        Sat, 27 Jan 2018 08:11:51 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1517069511; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=07Y35MO83L4SMj+cLDZPmhkkiHjrBmw2HZulS73g/4A0LtkCkSkwYmqcZuDLxTnRyn
         5LGiJ1YYcA5g2h9DqaadkA/YcJRic4dLCCFAP5Yma4Rj7Hj4YjG2G/zV3MGr4Orq8qkB
         bKsvi8SmLd8auD+aKTDDWegMznVSQ/XM1jUNHYEa7bN6nkseveO5nDV1Bjulf/wmBGuI
         19rVidGytcVR55NqNmYbvSlUhYk3jbaQsElGVFhSpb38vmR8G2nWuhNZr5zNHhWN+yQf
         cvXPwGP5uOiTZ8kkjASULaAB3AWLElZOVWaUa1ybUedrWbzXMHnB2pYjJ8HQ84vyypJZ
         AU0Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=user-agent:message-id:from:date:content-transfer-encoding
         :mime-version:subject:to:dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
        bh=K0p6ruI7I2CcJa84gcLB86wosBon4jYn916sZo4QALs=;
        b=jwoCrqatKDH0VTcZmYyzpHBMBBnYagKbip9+QI97ic7lGTj9WCtjiFq6ud97Pfvq6H
         r6v2e+4Ew4isB7lPea1BeYDZneRxLHNWeFnmCeCRYiF3p+PoOEKSFBrKqY6AwbDNEidB
         U6RPdPdSjM4Kn3KiFq4tY2kIZVH4ThJUe9uZ3TAx9lPcsyh1a1byJkbeTrFKD/wdETGj
         5N3Bj+1IO44KGeg4RQe/AgmailMQJCYmDJ1ohvP2l6dhEhrnJeJJ59NkbX8aDfXdIwNN
         WNfWxN37z2MrC4M79aw0FgeCiF+Wq9xXm/HkXR0TMgpq3FQ5+RJtGIwdYVvwhPtakp0p
         /wew==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mchromik.pl header.s=mail header.b=ot9QJQW9;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl designates 80.211.192.23 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=mchromik.pl
Return-Path: <chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl>
Received: from mx.mchromik.pl (mx.mchromik.pl. [80.211.192.23])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id x6si6936298wrg.120.2018.01.27.08.11.51
        for <donia.chromik@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 27 Jan 2018 08:11:51 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl designates 80.211.192.23 as permitted sender) client-ip=80.211.192.23;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mchromik.pl header.s=mail header.b=ot9QJQW9;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl designates 80.211.192.23 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=mchromik.pl
Received: by mx.mchromik.pl (Postfix, from userid 33) id C8DD15F895; Sat, 27 Jan 2018 17:11:49 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mchromik.pl; s=mail; t=1517069509; bh=K0p6ruI7I2CcJa84gcLB86wosBon4jYn916sZo4QALs=; h=To:Subject:Date:From:From; b=ot9QJQW98uRp0Szl599VV5Q5tM/0SVyaBWjxIhTpD/9yfRBmdL3MsvWot517+nhPf
     Xr77bRSrMSx0UEaC3sT72hJDua+CJsGcBPeBYCz7nNcaSzMpt6smHJUnepPa+RefQB
     mxzgHDPS5GAExvgxUjKMZYoLQJp32tl6Srjn4fyE=
To: donia.chromik@gmail.com
Subject: Cześć, chciałem sprawdzić czy działa.
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:rcube.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Date: Sat, 27 Jan 2018 17:11:49 +0100
From: chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl
Message-ID: <7c60f8247c4f533d8505104caca82abf@mchromik.pl>
X-Sender: chromik.maciej@mchromik.pl
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.1.5

Napisz mi jak to przeczytasz.
Pozdrawiam Cię bardzo.
Cześć
```

Comment: Open a ticket with Google.

Comment: I added the "code" formatting to your mail example, because it was practically an unreadable wall of text without it.

Comment: Cool, shiny new emails to add to my "marketing" list. I promise I only send hand picked junk spam and the finest malware you can find in Nigeria every minute.

Comment: but I'm scared. I have nothing. Your list does not work as you expect. What a pity

Comment: this clown really is trying to do it from ip: 91.200.12.166 try, try

Comment: there is nothing like a free server test;)

Comment: Can I give you a new port for the ssh server? Can you find it yourself?

Comment: How many IP addresses do you have five or ten?

Comment: walkerj235.com you must change ip address

Comment: @MaciejChromik provided you have good sending reputation there's not a lot you can do about this. IME Google doesn't seem to do anything with the "you're marking my emails as spam but they're not" tickets it gets, so unfortunately you just have to warn your Gmail recipients that they may not get to see your emails. At all. Not even in the junk folder.

Comment: ip 80.211.192.23 listed on dnsrbl.ru [http://multirbl.valli.org/lookup/80.211.192.23.html]  where are you getting 91.200.12.166 from?

Comment: My IP address is not on blacklists. IP 83 is simply the address from which attacks on my server took place after I wrote a comment to a "specialist" on marketing lists.

Answer (score 1):

No technical errors in your email, as far as I know. 
Move the messages out of Gmail's spam folder back into regular folders; maybe it helps Google's mystery/neural-net/hyper-Bayesian spam filter to learn that this new mail server is not a spam source.

Andu Rui F Ribeiro's comment was probably a sarcastic form of warning that you should not post your actual email addresses anywhere on web if you don't want them spammed. Sooner or later, maybe tomorrow, maybe a few months from now, some spammer spiders these pages looking for email addresses. And then your junk mail filters will suddenly be catching 10x to 50x as much junk as before.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is a test server on a cheap VPS. I would not mind if someone pinned him a bit, I would have a challenge. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should be using only ASCII in email headers: your `Subject:` line is bad, see [RFC2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) for what to do, and find some software to do that.

So far as I know `8BITMIME` does not exempt you from that.

Comment: I think that's not it